# Image View Not appearing above tabs Android

Tags: android, imageview

I Need to have an image view above my tabs. But the ImageView is not appearing device at all. In the device, the topmost is tabs with no image view. Below is my layout xml. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:background="@color/list_view_blue"
    />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment)
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem are in ur custom background, if u prove without background? 
or u you have to change in your onCreateView like below:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2m, container, false);

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout instead of Linear layout

Comment: Hi Sundeep, adding setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment) fixed the issue